# Are Black-Scholes Greeks bounded?

Tags: black-scholes, greeks

For time to maturity greater than zero, has it been proved somewhere that the Black-Scholes greeks
$$
\frac{\partial^n BS}{\partial x^n}
$$
are bounded, where $x := \log S$ and $S$ is the current spot price.

In other words, is there an expression and corresponding proof that
$$
\left| \frac{\partial^n BS}{\partial x^n} \right| \leq M(T-t)^{m(n)}
$$
for some constant $M$ and $m(n)$ some function of $n$?